# Issues regarding textareas inside a textarea

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to implement a feature where my users can change the HTML content on their blog. Recently I discovered that when you create a <`textarea`> field inside the `<textarea>` where the HTML-content is, the rest of the contents after `<textarea>` tag becomes invisible. It's kind of obvious to me why this happens, but is there a solution to this? The content is stored in a database and I'm wondering mainly if there is a fix for this in PHP.

My code is something like:

```
$input = "something <textarea>something</textarea>";
<textarea class="syntax-highlight"><?php echo $input; ?></textarea>
```

It was somehow difficult to explain myself, but please comment if any questions.

Comment: convert htmlentities on edit, then back on save. the user will be writing html and not a visual editor, right - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: You flat-out can't put a textarea within a textarea. Maybe you should explore [contenteditable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable)

Comment: So how come you can create textareas when editing Wordpress templates from wp-admin? It's basically the same thing, so I guess it's possible @StephenP

Comment: @kanarifugl I don't know Wordpress, but they could be using contenteditable, or the could be escaping and unescaping as Kai Qing's comment implies.

Comment: You should use htmlentities like @KaiQing says, rule-of-thumb.. if your going to echo out *any* user supplied data **anywhere** you should use htmlentities, its not only tags and quotes that will cause problems if you dont but XSS and CSRF attacks ect.

Comment: WP may have a JS based interpreter assisting in these areas. You can display changes in a normal html element, like a div, and write those changes to their raw form in a hidden textarea. Keep in mind, things like this are pretty advanced, so you're better off using htmlentities for simple needs. If you really need to display the textarea, look into the contenteditable option or whatever equivalents there are out there.